# Spring Tool Suite (STS) upgrade fails

Tags: windows, upgrade, spring-tool-suite

An **update** was downloaded automatically by my `2.6.3.RELEASE Build 201411281425`.
STS (Spring Tool Suite) asks to install it and when I click on the pop-up window it does some things and then stops with the following message which seem to indicate that it wants to delete itself.

I can understand why this fails but I am not sure why STS would think that this was possible.
I could not find any instructions about manually installing the zip file that is available as a download as an alternative way to upgrade my installation.

**How do I fix the automatic install or manually install the zip?**
(I am on Windows 7)

**Error message:**

```
An error occurred while uninstalling

session context was:
    (profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Uninstall,
     operand=[R]org.springsource.sts.ide.executable.win32.win32.x86_64
             3.6.3.201411281415-RELEASE-e44
     --> null,
         action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.natives.actions.CleanupzipAction).

Backup of file C:\RAMDrive\spring\STS.exe failed.
File that was copied to backup could not be deleted: C:\RAMDrive\spring\STS.exe
```

Answer (score 4):

Start the STS you want to upgrade and before you click on "Check for Upgrades", with STS still running, rename the STS.exe file you just started, to something else, like "STS_old.exe". That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

The message sounds strange, I've never seen this before. To install a fresh copy of STS, just download the ZIP file from the download page (the one that matches your operating system and pick the right 32bit or 64bit one, depending on your OS and the JDK you are using). Then unzip, and start STS.exe. That's it.